# Rails ActiveRecord Query - how to add a certain hour offset to every record in the created_at field in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-record-query

I need to run a group_by query in Ruby on Rails, but I first want to adjust all records in the created_at column by a certain hour amount before running the query. So, for example, adding 9 hours to every record in the created_at field, and then grouping by date.

Something like the following (which is incorrect):

```
 @foo = Bar.group("date(created_at + 9.hours)").count
```

How can I accomplish this in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has excellent support for manipulating dates and times (see [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html)). You can express '9 hours' as an `interval`, add it to a `timestamp`, and cast to a `date`:

```
=> select (now()::timestamp + '9 hours'::interval)::date;
    date    
------------
 2012-09-22
(1 row)
```

This ends up strikingly similar to your original pseudocode:

```
@foo = Bar.group("date(created_at + '9 hours'::interval)").count
```